# Registering Broadcast Receiver using Manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to work out an extension for Push Notification, where I don't have a package name of the application(since the extension is going to be used in any number of applications without modifying). I have the following information in the manifest -

```
<receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="App.package" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Receive the registration id -->
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
              <category android:name="App.package" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

The manifest can be used per app and need not to be included in the extension. Here's the IntentService and BroadCastReceiver code -

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    private static final String TAG = "INTENT_TAG";

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, LoaderActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

When I try sending the message from the server, the notification never gets called, as if the receiver never got instantiated or registered. Is it because both of my IntentService and BroacastReceiver are in default package?

Comment: I have created another question, since the problem was not what I originally thought - http://stackoverflow.com/q/19350641/1079901

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `GCMBroadcastReceiver` looks for `GcmIntentService` in the main package of the app, so it won't be found if it's in another package.

You can start the intent service with this code:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent gcmIntent = new Intent (context, GcmIntentService.class);
        gcmIntent.putExtras (intent.getExtras());
        startWakefulService(context, gcmIntent);
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

In addition, each app that uses your code (I'm not sure whether your code is supposed to be used as a library project or in some other way), must declare the broadcast receiver in its manifest with the correct package name in the category of the intent-filter. And you must define a permission for GCM that also includes that package name.

Comment: So the category name should be the package name which I have mentioned in the GCMIntentService/GCMBroadcastReceiver? Can that be different from the app's actual package name, so that I can define a generic package name for the extension? And in the permissions, which packagename is required, the extension's or the app's (in case keeping two of them different is allowed)?
It's like a library project, calling it a plugin would be a better terminology though :-)

Comment: No, the category name must be the package of the specific application that uses your GCM code (and the same package must be used in the permissions). Every app that uses your code will have a different package name, and therefore different category name and GCM permissions. The package name of the service class is a different issue. You should change your broadcast receiver code to stop looking for the service class in the main package of the app, and instead look for it in the package of your extension.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I hope that should be easily resolvable.

Comment: I've tried it resolving by changing the package of Both intent service and broadcastreceiver. The app finds it now. I've never used IntentService/Boradcastreceiver before, so I am missing some basci things here. Can you tell me if I need to start the service in code or will it be started automatically. I am considering doing it via code, since it's still not working.

Comment: @Creator I edited my answer to add code for starting the service from the broadcast receiver. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I finally got what all this IntentService and BroadcastReceiver means. I was having some confusion. The problem is my broadcastreceiver's onReceive method gets called in start, as soon as I load the extension and eventually the intent service gets called too. The onReceive of the receiver never gets called again even if I send the message to the device using my server.

Comment: Let me know if I need to provide any more info on this. I am using the following tutorial just for the server side code.  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/