# Android push notifications, not granting permission

Tags: android, push-notification, react-native

I'm trying to enable notifications on my android app (built in react-native) using [this package](https://github.com/oney/react-native-gcm-android)

Here is a part of my **MANIFEST.XML** file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="{package_name}"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0.0"
 android:minSdkVersion="21"
 android:targetSdkVersion="23">

<permission
    android:name="com.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" /> 

...

<receiver
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
  android:exported="true"
  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <category android:name="com.xxx" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.oney.gcm.GcmRegistrationService"/>
<service android:name="com.oney.gcm.BackgroundService"></service>

<service
  android:name="com.oney.gcm.RNGcmListenerService"
  android:exported="false" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
<receiver
  android:exported="false"
  android:name="com.oney.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.oney.gcm.GCMReceiveNotification" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name="io.neson.react.notification.NotificationEventReceiver" />
<receiver android:name="io.neson.react.notification.NotificationPublisher" />
<receiver android:name="io.neson.react.notification.SystemBootEventReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Unfortunately, I have this in my logs when I install my app :

`W/PackageManager( 873): Not granting permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND to package (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be46)`

Any thoughts on the issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: gone through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350641/broadcastreceiver-doesnt-get-called-when-using-it-for-push-notification ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a C2DM setup issue at your project level.Either go through [official doc](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) or follow this [tutorial](http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/) step by step.

Step to be made while changing your `Manifest.xml`

- Permission to receive C2DM messages
- Access to the internet
- Restrict access to your C2DM messages so no other app can see them
- Declare a Receiver, that we’ll create later, that will let us receive the C2DM events
- Make sure that the minSdkVersion is set so that only 2.2 and higher can access your app

Comment: I think he should move to GCM

Comment: This message is gone, thanks. But I still get a 401 error when trying to test my notifications with a curl request at [https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send](https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send)...

Comment: Go to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521459/gcm-http-401-authorization-error

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are using deprecated api

> Important: C2DM was officially deprecated on June 26, 2012, and will
>   be shut down completely as of October 20, 2015. Existing C2DM
>   developers are encouraged to migrate to Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).
>   See the C2DM-to-GCM Migration document for more information.
>   Developers must use GCM for new development.

https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?csw=1#manifest